Prime counting in some specific interval
I am interested in the ratio (R) of the number of prime numbers in certain intervals. Let N be a sufficient large positive integer. Let's define two intervals
$$I_a = \{\frac{1}{3}N,...,\frac{1}{2}N\}$$
$$I_b = \{\frac{1}{5}N,...,\frac{1}{4}N\}$$
Let's compare the number of primes in $I_a$ with the primes in $I_b$. According to the PNT the number of primes equal or less than N is approximately equal to $\frac{N}{log(N)}$. This implies that...

The primes in $I_a$ are approximately equal to $\quad \pi(I_a) = \bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{2}N}{log(\frac{1}{2}N)} - \frac{\frac{1}{3}N}{log(\frac{1}{3}N)}\bigg)$
The primes in $I_b$ are approximately equal to $\quad \pi(I_b) = \bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{4}N}{log(\frac{1}{4}N)} - \frac{\frac{1}{5}N}{log(\frac{1}{5}N)}\bigg)$

Now we have $R = \frac{\pi(I_a)}{\pi(I_b)}$.
What can we say about R? I checked it numerically and it seems that R tends to $\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{10}} = \frac{10}{3}$.

Can we proof this analytic, instead of numerical?

Have you tried "simply" writing down $R$ in terms of the expressions you get out of the PNT and simplifying the fraction? I would guess that that would work.

This way you get a very rough limit. For more precise results , try Li(x) or at least the Dusart bounds.

You just need to go further with your expansion of $R$. Even using the approximations you have for $\pi(x)$, you can derive the limit $\frac{10}{3}$.

@Peter, thx. I tried Li(x). I, roughly, get the same result of 1/3 and 1/10 when N goes to $10^{250}$. Do I miss the point?
